# How to Send All Data From SQLite to Server in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

Here I am sending data from local data base to mysql database server but aly first row data is uploading 
Can anyone help me

here i am fetching data from sqlite  using model class and display in recyclerview 
now i want to send all recyclerview data in ARRAY or any other way to server database

Here 6 images are fetch from sqlite also send to server without setImage in UI directly want to send to Server

Thanks in advance....!!!

Activity Code

```
   public class FetchLocalInsuranceListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    protected ViewDialog viewDialog;
    private RecyclerView recyclerview;
    RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private MyCustomAdapter myCustomAdapter;
    Context context;
    DatabaseHelper database;
    List<DataModel> datamodel;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fetch_local_insurance_list);
        context = this;
        datamodel = new ArrayList<DataModel>();
        viewDialog = new ViewDialog(this);
        viewDialog.setCancelable(false);

        database = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        datamodel = database.getAllSyncData();

        recyclerview = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view__local_my_insurance);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(FetchLocalInsuranceListActivity.this);
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerview.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true);
        myCustomAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(datamodel);
        recyclerview.setAdapter(myCustomAdapter);


    }

    public class MyCustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyCustomAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

        private List<DataModel> moviesList;

        public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            public TextView farmer_name, tv_Tagging_Date, tv_insurance_id;

            protected ImageButton editButton;

            public MyViewHolder(View view) {
                super(view);

                farmer_name = view.findViewById(R.id.text_insured_name);
                tv_Tagging_Date = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_Tagging_Date);
                tv_insurance_id = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_insurance_id);
                editButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.edit_button);
            }

        }


        public MyCustomAdapter(List<DataModel> moviesList) {
            this.moviesList = moviesList;
        }

        @Override
        public MyCustomAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.layout_local_insurance_list, parent, false);

            return new MyCustomAdapter.MyViewHolder(itemView);
        }

        public void clear() {
            int size = this.moviesList.size();
            if (size > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                    this.moviesList.remove(0);
                }

                this.notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, size);
            }
        }

        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(MyCustomAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {


            final DataModel datum = moviesList.get(position);
            Log.e("image", datum.getAnimal_Tail_Photo() + "");

            holder.farmer_name.setText("Farmer Name : " + datum.getFarmer_name() + "");
            holder.tv_Tagging_Date.setText("Tagging Date : " + datum.getTagging_date() + "");
            holder.tv_insurance_id.setText("#SNV_INSURANCE_" + datum.getId() + "  ");
            holder.editButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    editDataParticularRow(datum);
                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return moviesList.size();
        }

    }


    private void editDataParticularRow(DataModel dataModel) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(FetchLocalInsuranceListActivity.this, EditBankAndFarmerActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("BANK_ID", dataModel.getId() + "");
        Log.e("id", dataModel.getId() + "");
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    protected final void hideProgressDialog() {
        viewDialog.dismiss();

    }

    protected void showProgressDialog() {
        viewDialog.show();
    }

    protected void showProgressDialog(String message) {

        showProgressDialog();

    }

    public void doNormalPostOperation(final int i) {
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(FetchLocalInsuranceListActivity.this);
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(FetchLocalInsuranceListActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Saving Name...");
        progressDialog.show();


        final StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://thelastoffers.com/snv/webservices/test.php",
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();

                        database.deleteData(Integer.parseInt(datamodel.get(i).getId() + ""));

                        database.deleteAnimalData(Integer.parseInt(datamodel.get(i).getFarmer_id() + ""));


                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();

                        Toast.makeText(FetchLocalInsuranceListActivity.this, "Something went Wrong.. Please Try again..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();


                //    params.put("id", datamodel.get(i).getINSURANCE_ID() + "");

                // REMAINING PARAMS WITH SAME datamodel.get(i) item

                params.put("type", "insertOfflineData");

                params.put("id", datamodel.get(i).getINSURANCE_ID() + "");
                params.put("head_image_blob", String.valueOf(datamodel.get(i).getAnimal_Tag_Photo()));
                params.put("farmer_bank_hypo", datamodel.get(i).getFarmer_bank_hypo() + "");
                params.put("farmer_name", datamodel.get(i).getFarmer_name() + "");
                params.put("farmer_village", datamodel.get(i).getVillage() + "");
                params.put("farmer_taluka", datamodel.get(i).getTaluka() + "");
                params.put("farmer_district", datamodel.get(i).getDistrict() + "");
                params.put("tagging_date", datamodel.get(i).getTagging_date() + "");

                Log.e("Data", params + "");
                return params;
            }

        };

        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.sync_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_sync:
                for (int i = 0; i < datamodel.size(); i++) {

                    doNormalPostOperation(i);

                }

                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}
```

Database Code

```
 public List<DataModel> getAllSyncData() {
    List<DataModel> data = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT *  FROM FARMER_SYNC_TABLE LEFT JOIN ANIMAL_SYNC_TABLE ON farmer_id = new_insurane_id ORDER BY new_insurane_id DESC";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    Log.e("value", query + ";" + " ");

    StringBuilder stringBuffer = new StringBuilder();

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

            DataModel dataModel_1 = new DataModel();

            int NEW_INSURANCE_ID_1 = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("new_insurane_id"));
            String INSURANCE_ID_1 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("insurance_id"));
            String INSURED_NAME_1 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("insured_name"));
            String BANKHYPO_NAME_1 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("bankhypo_name"));
            String FARMER_NAME_1 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("farmer_name"));
            String VILLAGE_1 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("village"));
            String TALUKA_1 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("taluka"));
            String DISTRICT_1 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("district"));
            String TAGGING_DATE_1 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("tagging_date"));
            int NEW_ANIMAL_ID = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("new_animal_id"));
            int FARMER_ID_1 = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("farmer_id"));
            String TAG_COLUMN_1 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("tag_no"));
            String ANIMAL_EAR_POSITION_COLUMN_1 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("animal_ear_position"));
            String ANIMAL_SPECIES_COLUMN_1 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("animal_species"));
            String ANIMAL_BREED_COLUMN_1 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("animal_breed"));
            String ANIMAL_BODY_COLOR_COLUMN_1 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("animal_body_color"));
            String ANIMAL_SHAPE_RIGHT_COLUMN_1 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("animal_shape_right"));
            String ANIMAL_SHAPE_LEFT_COLUMN_1 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("animal_shape_left"));
            String ANIMAL_SWITCH_OF_TAIL_COLUMN_1 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("animal_sitch_of_tail"));
            String AGE_COLUMN_1 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("age_years"));
            String ANIMAL_OTHER_MARKS_COLUMN_1 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("animal_other_marks"));
            String PRAG_STATUS_COLUMN_1 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("prag_status"));
            String NUMBER_OF_LACTATION_COLUMN_1 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("number_of_lactation"));
            String CURRENT_MILK_COLUMN_1 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("current_milk"));
            String SUM_INSURED_COLUMN_1 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("sum_insured"));



            dataModel_1.setId(NEW_INSURANCE_ID_1);
            dataModel_1.setINSURANCE_ID(INSURANCE_ID_1);
            dataModel_1.setFarmer_insure_name(INSURED_NAME_1);
            dataModel_1.setFarmer_bank_hypo(BANKHYPO_NAME_1);
            dataModel_1.setFarmer_name(FARMER_NAME_1);
            dataModel_1.setVillage(VILLAGE_1);
            dataModel_1.setTaluka(TALUKA_1);
            dataModel_1.setDistrict(DISTRICT_1);
            dataModel_1.setTagging_date(TAGGING_DATE_1);
            dataModel_1.setAnimal_id(NEW_ANIMAL_ID);
            dataModel_1.setFarmer_id(FARMER_ID_1);
            dataModel_1.setTag_no(TAG_COLUMN_1);
            dataModel_1.setEar_position(ANIMAL_EAR_POSITION_COLUMN_1);
            dataModel_1.setAnimal_species(ANIMAL_SPECIES_COLUMN_1);
            dataModel_1.setAnimal_breed(ANIMAL_BREED_COLUMN_1);
            dataModel_1.setBody_color(ANIMAL_BODY_COLOR_COLUMN_1);
            dataModel_1.setShape_right(ANIMAL_SHAPE_RIGHT_COLUMN_1);
            dataModel_1.setShape_left(ANIMAL_SHAPE_LEFT_COLUMN_1);
            dataModel_1.setTail_switch(ANIMAL_SWITCH_OF_TAIL_COLUMN_1);
            dataModel_1.setAge(AGE_COLUMN_1);
            dataModel_1.setOther_marks(ANIMAL_OTHER_MARKS_COLUMN_1);
            dataModel_1.setPrag_status(PRAG_STATUS_COLUMN_1);
            dataModel_1.setLactations(NUMBER_OF_LACTATION_COLUMN_1);
            dataModel_1.setMilk_qty(CURRENT_MILK_COLUMN_1);
            dataModel_1.setSum_insured(SUM_INSURED_COLUMN_1);

            dataModel_1.setAnimal_Tag_Photo(Utils.getBitmapFromByte(cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex("tag_image"))));
            dataModel_1.setAnimal_Head_Photo(Utils.getBitmapFromByte(cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex("head_image"))));
            dataModel_1.setAnimal_Left_Photo(Utils.getBitmapFromByte(cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex("left_side_image"))));
            dataModel_1.setAnimal_Right_Photo(Utils.getBitmapFromByte(cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex("right_side_image"))));
            dataModel_1.setAnimal_Tail_Photo(Utils.getBitmapFromByte(cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex("tail_image"))));
            dataModel_1.setAnimal_Farmer_Photo(Utils.getBitmapFromByte(cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex("farmer_image"))));



            stringBuffer.append(dataModel_1);
            data.add(dataModel_1);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    db.close();
    return data;


}
```

Comment: Convert all data of table into a json format via GSON library and send this json data to server via API

Comment: can you help me how to do that sry but pls @SurajVaishnav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple problem. You are only using 
use for loop to iterate through all items like,

```
for(int i=0; i<datamodel.size(); i++){
 doNormalPostOperation(i)
}
```

and in doNormalPostOperation method

```
public void doNormalPostOperation(int i) {

  // PREVIOUS CODE
 @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
     params.put("id", datamodel.get(i).getINSURANCE_ID() + "");

    // REMAINING PARAMS WITH SAME datamodel.get(i) item

   }
}
```

which is causing that issue and **only sending first item**.  You will need to ***iterate*** through all items to **generate parameters and send to server**, or else you can combine them to one **json array and modify the code server side**.

Comment: Thanks bro its working

but issue is that if new record added in sqlite and again send to server its sending previous data also again in database

Comment: Try small workaround, add one extra column in your local sqlite with boolean type and named "sync", and set it to true when once you send it to online database. and next time only send items which are not set sync column to true. :), keep this column false by default.

Answer (score 1):

You can go through this:

1. Get all the data which you want to send, via select query and store this data in a array list.
2. Using GSON library you can convert that arraylist into json data
3. Now you have to create an API which receive that json data and parse it and insert every record to database.
4. On the app end you have to hit that API and pass json data to it.

Comment: Can you do all steps pls in code or send  me code so i can understand properly

Comment: It takes time to code, you have to try it by yourself and let me know if you stuck anywhere.

Comment: Check these:
https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-sync-sqlite-database-with-server/,

http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/how-to-sync-sqlite-on-android-to-mysql-db/

Comment: I already try this example but in this the data fetch from recyclerview and send to server but i want to send all data from Model class to server

Comment: You check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983761/android-java-simple-send-and-receive-with-server-fast-setup-challenge

There is also a video tutorial on youtube in 2 parts:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RDOkQ_P7esU

Comment: you want this, but from where?

Comment: from sqlite database

Comment: I have mentioned steps in the answer, in which step you are facing problem?

Comment: I can't give you entire code because of time issue, but you can check this link:
https://coderanch.com/t/616349/ArrayList-SQLite-Database

Comment: email id please so i can share multiple files

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189677/discussion-between-suraj-vaishnav-and-manav-isarani).

Comment: I have updated my answer Suraj Vaishnav pls help me

Answer (score 1):

```
    First you collect the Data from sqltables

    /* Collecting Information */

    public Cursor getAllData() {
       String selectQuery = "Select * from "+TABLE_MEMBER; 
         SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
         Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
         return cursor;
    }


    public JSONObject createJsonObject(){
        Cursor cursor = getAllData(); 
        JSONObject jobj ;
        JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
        cursor.moveToFIrst();
        while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
            jobj = new JSONObject();
            jboj.put("Id", cursor.getInt("Id"));
            jboj.put("Name", cursor.getString("Name"));
            arr.put(jobj);
        }
        jobj = new JSONObject();
        jobj.put("data", arr);
    }


public void postJsonToServer(){
   JSONObject js = createJsonObject();
   String url = "YOUR -- Post Url";
   JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(
        Request.Method.POST,url, js,
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                msgResponse.setText(response.toString());
                hideProgressDialog();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                hideProgressDialog();
            }
        }) {

    /**
     * Passing some request headers
     * */
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
         HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
         headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        return headers;
    }
}
```